# unable to upload photos on web server using php

Tags: php

i am able to upload photos on my machine running wampserver but when i upload the same php script on web server, it is not uploading the photo.

here is my html form

```html
<form action="http://localhost/sample/imageupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and this is my imageupload php code:

```js
<?php


echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />" ;
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />" ;
echo "Size: " . ( $_FILES["file"]["size"] /1024 ) . " Kb<br />" ;
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] ;

if (file_exists("/images/home" .$_FILES["file"]["name"] ) )
{
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists." ;
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] ,"/images/home" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] ) ;


}



?>
```

/images/home is the directory i have created on web server using cpanel.
please help...

Comment: "/images/home" you missed `/`. It should be "/images/home/"

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @LearneR ツ did that but still no uploading.

Comment: Any error? Are you getting `FILE` data on form submit?

Comment: @ LearneR ツ i removed the very first forward slash / and it is working now. thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You are using local file path as action url.It won't work in hosted server.
Please try below code.

```
<form action="imageupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: i did that before uploading php script on web server.the problem was with upload directory address.i was using /images/home , i changed it to images/home and it worked.